# Unit testing MFC UI applications?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, user-interface, mfc, tdd

How do you unit test a large MFC UI application?

We have a few large MFC applications that have been in development for many years, we use some standard automated QA tools to run basic scripts to check fundamentals, file open etc. These are run by the QA group post the daily build.

But we would like to introduce procedures such that individual developers can build and run tests against dialogs, menus, and other visual elements of the application before submitting code to the daily build.

I have heard of such techniques as hidden test buttons on dialogs that only appear in debug builds, are there any standard toolkits for this.

Environment is C++/C/FORTRAN, MSVC 2005, Intel FORTRAN 9.1, Windows XP/Vista x86 & x64.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on how the App is structured. If logic and GUI code is separated (MVC) then testing the logic is easy. Take a look at Michael Feathers ["Humble Dialog Box"](https://web.archive.org/web/20080509080327/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf) (PDF).

EDIT: If you think about it: You should very carefully refactor if the App is not structured that way. There is no other technique for testing the logic. Scripts which simulate clicks are just scratching the surface.

It is actually pretty easy:

Assume your control/window/whatever changes the contents of a listbox when the user clicks a button and you want to make sure the listbox contains the right stuff after the click.

1. Refactor so that there is a separate list with the items for the listbox to show. The items are stored in the list and are not extracted from whereever your data comes from. The code that makes the listbox list things knows only about the new list.
2. Then you create a new controller object which will contain the logic code. The method that handles the button click only calls mycontroller->ButtonWasClicked(). It does not know about the listbox or anythings else.
3. MyController::ButtonWasClicked() does whats need to be done for the intended logic, prepares the item list and tells the control to update. For that to work you need to decouple the controller and the control by creating a interface (pure virtual class) for the control. The controller knows only an object of that type, not the control.

Thats it. The controller contains the logic code and knows the control only via the interface. Now you can write regular unit test for MyController::ButtonWasClicked() by mocking the control. If you have no idea what I am talking about, read Michaels article. Twice. And again after that.
(Note to self: must learn not to blather that much)

Answer (score 14):

Since you mentioned MFC, I assumed you have an application that would be hard to get under an automated test harness. You'll observe best benefits of unit testing frameworks when you build tests as you write the code.. But trying to add a new feature in a test-driven manner to an application which is not designed to be testable.. can be hard work and well frustrating.

Now what I am going to propose is definitely **hard work**.. but with some discipline and perseverance you'll see the benefit soon enough.

- First you'll need some management backing for new fixes to take a bit longer. Make sure everyone understands why.
- Next buy a copy of the [WELC book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052). Read it cover to cover if you have the time OR if you're hard pressed, scan the index to find the symptom your app is exhibiting. This book contains a lot of good advice and is just what you need when trying to get existing code testable.
  [image]
- Then for every new fix/change, spend some time and understand the area you're going to work on. Write some tests in a xUnit variant of your choice (freely available) to exercise current behavior.
- Make sure all tests pass. Write a new test which exercises needed behavior or the bug.
- Write code to make this last test pass.
- Refactor mercilessly within the area under tests to improve design.
- Repeat for every new change that you have to make to the system from here on. No exceptions to this rule.
- Now *the promised land*: Soon ever growing islands of well tested code will begin to surface. More and more code would fall under the automated test suite and changes will become progressively easier to make. And that is because slowly and surely the underlying design becomes more testable.

The easy way out was my previous answer. This is the difficult but right way out.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is a dated question, but for those of us who still work with MFC, the Microsoft C++ Unit Testing Framework in VS2012 works well.

**The General Procedure:**

1. Compile your MFC Project as a static library
2. Add a new Native Unit Test Project to your solution.
3. In the Test Project, add your MFC Project as a Reference.
4. In the Test Project's Configuration Properties, add the Include directories for your header files.
5. In the Linker, input options add your MFC.lib;nafxcwd.lib;libcmtd.lib;
6. Under 'Ignore Specific Default Libraries' add nafxcwd.lib;libcmtd.lib;
7. Under General add the location of your MFC exported lib file.

The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146338/error-lnk2005-new-and-delete-already-defined-in-libcmtd-libnew-obj has a good description of why you need the nafxcwd.lib and libcmtd.lib.

The other important thing to check for in legacy projects. In General Configuration Properties, make sure both projects are using the same 'Character Set'. If your MFC is using a Multi-Byte Character Set you'll need the MS Test to do so as well.

Answer (score 3):

Though not perfect, the best I have found for this is AutoIt http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3

"AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying "runtimes" required!"

This works well when you have access to the source code of the application being driven, because you can use the resource ID number of the controls you want to drive.  In this way you do not have to worry about simulated mouse clicks on particular pixels.  Unfortunately,  in a legacy application, you may well find that the resource ID are not unique, which may cause problems.  However. it is very straightforward to change the IDs to be unique and rebuild.

The other issue is that you will encounter timing problems.  I do not have a tried and true solution for these.  Trial and error is what I have used, but this is clearly not scalable.  The problem is that the AutoIT script must wait for the test application to respond to a command before the script issues the next command or check for the correct response.  Sometimes it is not easy to find a convenient event to wait and watch for.

My feeling is that, in developing a new application, I would insist on a consistent way to signal "READY".  This would be helpful to the human users as well as test scripts!  This may be a challenge for a legacy application, but perhaps you can introduce it in problematical points and slowly spread it to the entire application as maintenance continues.

Comment: I like the functionality of AutoIt3 but question was about unit testing and you are talking about UI integration test. They are two different tests.

Answer (score 2):

Although it cannot handle the UI side, I unit test MFC code using the Boost Test library.  There is a Code Project article on getting started:

[Designing Robust Objects with Boost](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Designing_Robust_Objects.aspx)

Comment: I am considering this unit testing framework for our MFC applications. But I would like to test UI logics too. I understand it would be impossible to test view class. But how about Document class? I am thinking to make Document class acts as Presenter of MVP and to test UI logics by implementing unit tests on that class like we do test controller class in MVC. Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 1):

Well we have one of these humongous MFC Apps at the workplace. Its a gigantic pain to maintain or extend... its a huge ball of mud now but it rakes in the moolah.Anyways

- We use [**Rational Robot**](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/robot/) for doing smoke tests and the like.
- Another approach that has had some success is to create a small product-specific language and **script tests** that use VBScript and some Control handle spying magic. Turn common actions into commands.. e.g. OpenDatabase would be a command that in turn will inject the required script blocks to click on Main Menu > File > "Open...". You then create excel sheets which are a series of such commands. These commands can take parameters too. Something like a FIT Test.. but more work. Once you have most of the common commands identified and scripts ready. It's pick and assemble scripts (tagged by CommandIDs) to write new tests. A test-runner parses these Excel sheets, combines all the little script blocks into a test script and runs it.

  1. OpenDatabase "C:\tests\MyDB"
  2. OpenDialog "Add Model"
  3. AddModel "M0001", "MyModel", 2.5, 100
  4. PressOK
  5. SaveDatabase

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have been using Rational Team Test, then Robot, but in recent discussions with Rational we discovered they have no plans to support Native x64 applications focusing more on .NET, so we decided to switch Automated QA tools. This is great but licensing costs don't allow us to enable it for all developers.

All our applications support a COM API for scripting, which we regression test via VB, but this tests the API no the application as such.

Ideally I would be interested on how people integrate cppunit and similar unit testing frameworks into the application at a developer level.