# error LNK2005: new and delete already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, lnk2005

I have a Visual studio 2005 solution that has two projects. One is a static library and the other is a executable used to test the features in the static library. The static library uses MFC. I got the following errors when I built the solution.

```
uafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)
uafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??    3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgdel.obj)
uafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int)" (??_U@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(newaop.obj)
uafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete[](void *)" (??_V@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(delete2.obj)
```

I do not know how to overcome this. Can some one please explain why this error is occuring. Any explanation that gives an overview of .lib files linkage will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the other (non-static-library) project a CRT project?

Comment: If the other (non static library) project is a CRT project, check out this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652

Comment: I got this error trying to compile a console app from the command-line with `cl`. I didn’t have it until I `#includ`ed one of my libraries that uses MFC’s `CString`. Thanks to the KB article, I just moved my `#include` up and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 76):

The CRT libraries use weak external linkage for the new, delete, and DllMain functions. The MFC libraries also contain new, delete, and DllMain functions. These functions require the MFC libraries to be linked before the CRT library is linked. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652

Solution based on VS2005 (Replace Nafxcwd.lib with Uafxcwd.lib for ~VS2013)

go to project>properties>configuration properties>linker>input

add to "Additional dependency"  -> Nafxcwd.lib Libcmtd.lib

add to "ignore specific library"  -> Nafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib

order of libraries is important( Nafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib).

Comment: If you're compiling with unicode you want to use uafxcwd.lib instead of nafxcwd.lib.  Note that the d is only for debug builds as well.  In you're release configuration use uafxcw.lib and libcmt.lib

Comment: I put them in additional dependencies as suggested (in front of anything else I had) but did not need to put them in "ignore specific library". For any of those looking, this is "how you solve a dependency problem" as suggested by Step 2 of [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B148652&x=13&y=8) frequently linked to for issues like this.

Answer (score 17):

One thing to try is to make sure you have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

as the first line in your .cpp files. I'm sure that's not the answer in all cases, but it made the identical error go away in my case.

Comment: I don't know if I'm going crazy, but I tried your answer after the other options failed to work. The error(s) went away. I then removed the line to make a note of the exact nature of the errors... and they didn't come back?! hmm c++ compiler errors are cryptic to say the least...

Comment: I independently came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me too.  I suspect it is due to what is included by stdafx.h.  I wonder whether removing the stdafx.h include from all files and removing stdafx.cpp would have the same effect?

Answer (score 17):

I meet this problem in **a MFC solution of Visual Studio 2010**, while changing `Use MFC in a Shared DLL` into `Use MFC in a Static Library` in **Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General**.

I solve the problem by the following ways, please locate **Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input** at first.

In Debug mode:

- Add `uafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib` in **Additional Dependencies**.
- Add `uafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib` in **Ignore Specific Default Libraries**.

In Release mode:

- Add `uafxcw.lib;Libcmt.lib` in **Additional Dependencies**.
- Add `uafxcw.lib;Libcmt.lib` in **Ignore Specific Default Libraries**.

Notice:

1. Don't miss the `;` between the two `.lib` files.
2. A suffix `-d` must be added in the files in Debug mode.

Answer (score 7):

be sure that you have `#include <afx.h>` in `"stdafx.h"` BEFORE other includes like `#include <string>`

Answer (score 5):

in  config linker input

- In additional dependicies  put **uafxcw.lib;LIBCMT.lib**
- In Ignore specific put put **uafxcw.lib;LIBCMT.lib**

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the C++ runtime library that you are linking with is the same on your static library as well as your executable. Check your project properties C/C++->Code generation->runtime library settings.

Answer (score 2):

Typo. One stupid way you got that is instead of include the header, you inlucde the cpp.
e.g.

```
#include <myclass.cpp> //should be #include <myClass.h>
```

Comment: Correct. This happened in my case. I kept all the function and class definitions in the cpp, and got this error. When I shifted the definitions to a hpp file, the errors went away. Weird!

Answer (score 1):

First, libcmtd.lib is for a debug version and libcmt.lib is for production.  Double-check that you're not including both. One place to check is the "Command Line" section of the Configuration Properties/Linker project properties.

If you go to the properties for the project, and open up the Configuration Properties/Linker/Input section, you can "Ingore Specific Library"...try listing libcmtd.lib in that field.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have a static library compiled with _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC, and the application not compiled with _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC, I was receiving then LNK2005. I've changed the application to compile with _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC, and the LNK2005 disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Got rid of the problem

```
uafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : warning LNK4006: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned __int64)"
```

- In additional dependicies put `uafxcw.lib`.
- In Ignore specific put put `uafxcw.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I had created two fresh projects with VS2017, one was working the other not, so I compared what was the difference. The one working was created with 
 `File > New Project > Visual C++ > MFC/ATL > MFC Application`
 the one not working was created with 
`File > New Project > Visual C++ > Windows Desktop > Windows Desktop Wizard`
then adding MFC. In both cases I was using MFC as static lib. I had figured out two fixes. But before that we have to add imports because the second project had NONE!

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
```

Now either of the two fixes worked for me:

1. `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Use of MFC` set it to use in a Shared DLL, this should also automatically set `C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library` to `Multi-threaded debug dll /MDd` make sure it indeed did that.
   Try compile now, for me it worked.
2. I noticed the working project had some imports in stdafx.h, I copied them into pch.h in the other project, it worked.(Keeping the properties unchanged, so static lib was used). The code copied was this:

```cpp
#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS      // some CString constructors will be explicit

// turns off MFC's hiding of some common and often safely ignored warning messages
#define _AFX_ALL_WARNINGS
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions


#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
```

The other solutions changing Linker settings I tried them but they did not work.
I would appreciate if somebody knows why my solution works, it is weird, why including those headers in `pch.h` solves a linker issue whereas including those same headers anywhere else triggers that error??

Comment: The pch.h file is generated as a precompiled header.  You can turn them off for the project using Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers and selecting "Not using precompiled headers".

You can also disable precompiled headers for individual C/C++ files by right-clicking the file in Solution Explorer and going through the properties menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manifest file of both projects, make sure that they are linking the same version of the standard library. Most likely they are not, check the properties->code generation->standard library linking.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem. The link given by Donnie explains the the reason. The solution was to look at the error messages and then removing those libs involved and adding those libs in the order of MFC libs first and then CRT libs.

The way to do that in vs2008 is given by ali.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add that if you have replaced the new/delete operators (and if so, please do the array and the scalar both), you may need to tag them as __forceinline so that the obj doesn't collide with the lib.

For example, I did these to force aligned allocations and had the same trouble until I did that:

```
__forceinline void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    return _aligned_malloc(size, 16);
}
__forceinline void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    _aligned_free(ptr);
}
__forceinline void * operator new [](size_t size)
{
    return _aligned_malloc(size, 16);
}
__forceinline void operator delete [](void* ptr)
{
    _aligned_free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I believe `inline` is sufficient. After all, you don't really care, whether those calls get inlined or not. You just need to be able to have multiple definitions (in different translation units), and that's what [inline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) buys you.

Answer (score 0):

A header file declared and defined a variable. Possible solutions include:
Declare the variable in .h: extern BOOL MyBool; and then assign to it in a .c or .cpp file: BOOL MyBool = FALSE;.
Declare the variable static.
Declare the variable selectany.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by changing

> Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General: Use of
>   MFC = Use MFC in a Shared DLL

Before it was set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries"

Additionally I had to set the /MD option under

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation : Runtime Library =
>   Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause that I ran across while searching for this answer:

I accidentally left an `#include "StdAfx.h"` line at the top of a .cpp file that I moved from the application (which uses precompiled headers) into a shared static library (which doesn't use precompiled headers).

Answer (score 0):

Got errors after applying Cipher Saw's solution to vs2015

```
1>afxnmcdd.lib(wincore2.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __stdcall DDX_Control(class CDataExchange *,int,class CWnd &)" (?DDX_Control@@YGXPAVCDataExchange@@HAAVCWnd@@@Z) already defined in uafxcwd.lib(wincore2.obj)
1>afxnmcdd.lib(wincore2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall CWnd::ExecuteDlgInit(void *)" (?ExecuteDlgInit@CWnd@@QAEHPAX@Z) already defined in uafxcwd.lib(wincore2.obj)
1>afxnmcdd.lib(wincore2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall CMFCDynamicLayout::GetHostWndRect(class CRect &)const " (?GetHostWndRect@CMFCDynamicLayout@@QBEXAAVCRect@@@Z) already defined in uafxcwd.lib(wincore2.obj)
1>afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses(void)" (?AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses@@YAXXZ) already defined in uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall CMFCControlContainer::PreUnsubclassControl(class CWnd *)" (?PreUnsubclassControl@CMFCControlContainer@@IAEXPAVCWnd@@@Z) already defined in uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall CMFCControlContainer::SubclassDlgControls(void)" (?SubclassDlgControls@CMFCControlContainer@@QAEHXZ) already defined in uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
```

Was able to fix them by changing libs list from `uafxcw.lib;Libcmt.lib` to `afxnmcdd.lib;uafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib` (debug unicode build)