# Error LNK2005 DllMain already defined in uafxcw.lib(dllmodul.obj)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, linker-errors

I have dll project. I added to my solution other quite big project that I want to use as a lib in my dll. But when I started to use new project from my dll project, I had several linking errors, also like in this question [error LNK2005: new and delete already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146338/error-lnk2005-new-and-delete-already-defined-in-libcmtd-libnew-obj)

I've put into "Additional dependency" and "ignore specific library"  uafxcwd.lib;Libcmtd.lib, and errors about new, delete etc now is gone, but I still got the error about DllMain.

I've also tried to put

```
extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; }
```

line to the cpp with DllMain and got additional error

```
Error   LNK2005 __afxForceUSRDLL already defined in dllmain.obj
```

I'm completely at a loss

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc:[Linker Tools Error LNK2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=msvc-160)

If two objects define the same symbol, you get exactly this linker error. I suggest you could try to find out which of both libraries you actually need and then tell the linker not to use the other one.

And I suggest you should check the the linker order.The MFC libs need get linked first, and then the CRT libs could be linked.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link: [error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRT.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343368/error-lnk2005-dllmain12-already-defined-in-msvcrt-lib)

Comment: But I already have added to additional dependencies  uafxcwd.lib; I've also tried all other proposition from the link you've provided, still got same error and even more, when I tried to add extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; } to my cpp with dllMain

Comment: @Bruice I suggest you try to the code:

`#ifdef _X86_
extern "C" { int _afxForceUSRDLL; }
#else
extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; }
#endif`

Comment: I've tried this as as well, got additional "Error   LNK2005 __afxForceUSRDLL already defined in dllmain.obj " error

Comment: @Bruice _USRDLL and _AFXDLL conflict, I suggest you try the /MD compiler option:[Build Settings for an MFC DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa235516(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @Bruice I suggest you should provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a need to use my own DllMain, but it being already defined in a library that I also needed:

```
error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in uafxcw.lib(dllmodul.obj)
```

The fix from @Jeaninez to add

```
#ifdef _X86_ extern "C" 
  int _afxForceUSRDLL;  
#else 
  extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; } 
#endif
```

just before my own DllMain worked perfectly. Thanks.