# How to run MS Test with virtual methods (for C++/MFC code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, mstest, unit-testing

I am working on a project based upon MFC, building in Visual studio 2010.
I was hoping to ease some of the testing by creating a automate a few (unit) tests of some worker objects (non GUI classes).

Visual Studio 2010 got MS test, and this would be my preferred choice, due to the IDE integration.

However i my attempts failed quite quickly.
1) Add MS-test project
2) Include the source files for testing
3) Change CLR support from Safe -> pure (avoid errors)

The build fails when first interface is meet (my classes override this)
Note: The classes build fine in my MFC project.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
class ihttp_Common
{
public:
    virtual bool            IsExecuting() = 0;
    virtual CEvent&         ExecutionEnded() = 0;
//several other methods
};
```

I get the error:

```
 *1>c:\srcPath\SomeInterface.h(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'*
```

1. Am i defining my interfaces badly ?
2. Is MS-Test really incompatible with virtual methods

Comment: Where is CEvent defined?  Is it in a file that has been #included in stdafx.h?

Comment: yep, it should be in stdafx.h
Standard part of MFC

Comment: Is [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21445196/2065121) useful?

Comment: Try using a pre-declaration for CEvent and comment out stdafx.h